# LinkedIn Thumbnail Image Not Appearing

Tags: linkedin-api, thumbnails, yoast

Issue: LinkedIn does not generate a thumbnail image when sharing a blog post. Here’s an example blog post: https://blog.terkel.io/12-tips-to-improve-underperforming-blog-posts/

We have:

- Upgraded to the latest version of the Yoast SEO plugin
- Shared the url to Facebook and confirmed that the thumbnail image displays on their platform
- Viewed the source code to determine that the og:image appears, and the media file can render
- Analyzed the LinkedIn Post Inspector and determined that they are not detecting an image (image not found; same with the publish date field)

Our site has all the required meta tags for sharing on social media; see their recommendation at https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a521928. So it’s unclear why LinkedIn isn't picking those up.

What solutions would be recommended to get a thumbnail image to be detected and displayed on LinkedIn?

Answer (score 1):

Your `og:image` is a .webp file. Use a JPEG or PNG; in my experience, LinkedIn doesn't support WEBP images.

Comment: Hmm - thanks for this answer, it helped. I feel like we need to be able to downvote linkedin for not supporting webp :|