# Featured image not showing on LinkedIN post. Tried everything with DIVI support desk but no succes

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api, yoast, divi

Can someone maybe help me investigate this problem? We have added a few different code lines in the head and in the PHP.

The support desk advised me to ask my question here.

Is someone able to have a look?

https://www.roeljanssen.nl/2023/01/25/oliver-bullough-je-hoeft-geen-butler-van-kleptocraten-en-witwassers-te-zijn/

This is the article we would like to share on LinkedIN.

Many thanks for your support!

We used this link: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-in-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same problem not so long ago and I think I know why your featured image is not displaying when sharing the article on Linkedin.

They have posted an article explaining all the details about the featured content they are using for Linkedin posts : [Make your website shareable on Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a521928/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

Concerning the featured image, it is said that they are using the `<meta property='og:image'>` tag in the head of your page as the image that will be displayed on the post.
It is also said that this image needs to have at least a width of 1200px, and a height of 627px.

I've checked in the html code of the article you want to share, and noticed the featured image only has a width of 300px and a height of 200px.

The issue there might be that your image is just too small ( which was the case for me ).
Try using an image that matches their restrictions as your featured image, and it should be good.

I hope this answer can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a size issue, but more likely it's because your image is a WEBP file. See [LinkedIn Thumbnail Image Not Appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250914/linkedin-thumbnail-image-not-appearing).