# My website's featured images aren't displaying when sharing link on Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

When I post my website's homepage on LinkedIn, it doesn't show any image. The same goes for any articles I share.

I looked into the [LinkedIn Post Debugger](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fmetaroids.com%2F), and it says "No image found".

Please help

It makes no sense that LinkedIn doesn't detect my image because all of them are below 200KB
My homepage's og image is 1200x800. For the articles, all featured images are 1536x677

I've already made my homepage compliant to the Open Graph Protocol (OGP). I can find all the elements required by Linkedin [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a521928) on my website's viewsource page, which you can verify.

I've already refreshed cache a bunch of times. I already fixed this error with both Facebook and Twitter. Somehow only LinkedIn isn't working with me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For posting a question, it's best to include your code (your open graph meta data in this case). Looking at your webpage (the link was included in your link to LinkedIn's Post Debugger), you're supplying a webp image. Try changing your image to a jpg or png.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinkedIn Thumbnail Image Not Appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250914/linkedin-thumbnail-image-not-appearing)